# MemoryCache not accepting any expiration duration

Tags: c#, caching, memorycache

I have a very simple Code, but what it does it completely weird. It is a simple Cache abstraction and goes like this:

```
public class CacheAbstraction
{
    private MemoryCache _cache;

    public CacheAbstraction()
    {
        _cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions { });
    }

    public async Task<T> GetItemAsync<T>(TimeSpan duration, Func<Task<T>> factory, 
                                         [CallerMemberName] string identifier = null ) where T : class
    {
        return await _cache.GetOrCreateAsync<T>(identifier, async x =>
        {
            x.SetAbsoluteExpiration(DateTime.UtcNow.Add(duration));
            T result = null;
            result = await factory();
            return result;
        });
    }
}
```

Now the fun part: I'm passing expiration durations of 1h - 1d

If I run it in a test suite, everything is fine.

If I run it as a .net core app, the expiration is always set to "now" and the item expires on the next cache check. WTF!?

Comment: I have tested the function (for few hours) and it works well. In my assumption your problem is that the you are using the function SetAbsoluteExpiration with the parameter as DateTimeOffset. Even if you send an UTC value the function will work with the offset. Now if you have different servers is possible that the offsets to be different and that is why you have this strange behavior.

Comment: what should I be using instead of SetAbsoluteExpiration!?
I do understand the UTC offset topic, but that would explain a couple of hours and wouldn't set the whole thing to "now". And not on Tests only :(

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been two years, but I ran across this same problem (cache items seeming to expire instantly) recently and found a possible cause. Two essentially undocumented features in `MemoryCache`: **linked cache entries and options propagation**.

This allows a child cache entry object to passively propagate it's options up to a parent cache entry when the child goes out of scope.  This is done via `IDisposable`, which `ICacheEntry` [implements](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.2/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/CacheEntry.cs#L133) and is used internally by `MemoryCache` in [extension methods](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.2/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/src/MemoryCacheExtensions.cs#L44) like `Set()` and `GetOrCreate/Async()`.  What this means is that if you have "nested" cache operations, the inner ones will propagate their cache entry options to the outer ones, including cancellation tokens, expiration callbacks, and expiration times.

In my case, we were using `GetOrCreateAsync()` and a factory method that made use of a library which did its own caching using the same injected `IMemoryCache`.  For example:

```
public async Task<Foo> GetFooAsync() {
    return await _cache.GetOrCreateAsync("cacheKey", async c => {
        c.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
        return await _library.DoSomething();
    });
}
```

The library uses `IMemoryCache` internally (the same instance, injected via DI) to cache results for a few seconds, essentially doing this:

```
_cache.Set(queryKey, queryResult, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

Because `GetOrCreateAsync()` [is implemented](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.2/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/src/MemoryCacheExtensions.cs#L92) by creating a `CacheEntry` inside a `using` block, the effect is that the 5 second expiration used by the library propagates up to the parent cache entry in `GetFooAsync()`, resulting in the Foo object always only being cached for 5 seconds instead of 1 hour, **effectively expiring it immediately**.

DotNet Fiddle showing this behavior: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fo14BT

**You can avoid this propagation behavior in a few ways:**

(1) Use `TryGetValue()` and `Set()` instead of `GetOrCreateAsync()`

```
if (_cache.TryGetValue("cacheKey", out Foo result))
    return result;

result = await _library.DoSomething();
return _cache.Set("cacheKey", result, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
```

(2) Assign the cache entry options after invoking the other code that may also use the cache

```
return await _cache.GetOrCreateAsync("cacheKey", async c => {
    var result = await _library.DoSomething();
    // set expiration *after*
    c.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
    return result;
});
```

(and since `GetOrCreate/Async()` [does not prevent reentrancy](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36499), the two are effectively the same from a concurrency standpoint).

**Warning:** Even then it's easy to get wrong.  If you try to use `AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow` in option (2) it won't work because setting that property doesn't remove the `AbsoluteExpiration` value if it exists resulting in both properties having a value in the `CacheEntry`, and `AbsoluteExpiration` is honored before the relative.

For the future, Microsoft has [added a feature to control this behavior](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/45592) via a new property [`MemoryCacheOptions.TrackLinkedCacheEntries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycacheoptions.tracklinkedcacheentries?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0), but it won't be available until .NET 7.  Without this future feature, I haven't been able to think of a way for libraries to prevent propagation, aside from using a different `MemoryCache` instance.